# Xcode 10: unable to attach DB error

Tags: ios, xcodebuild, xcode10

When updating to Xcode 10, iOS static library target fails to build. Way how I am trying to build it is following:

```
xcodebuild -target TargetName -configuration Release clean build
```

With Xcode 9 everything runs smoothly, but when Xcode 10 is used for build, I am getting following error (after clean runs smoothly):

> note: Using new build system
>
> note: Planning build
>
> note: Constructing build description Build system information error:
>   unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database
>   "/Users/uerceg/random-path/build/XCBuildData/build.db": database is
>   locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same
>   filesystem location.
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> The following build commands failed:  PhaseScriptExecution
>   MultiPlatform\ Build
>   /Users/uerceg/random-path/build/Library.build/Release-iphoneos/LibraryTarget.build/Script-9DE7C9021AE68FA5001556E5.sh
>   (1 failure)

This probably unrelated, but I noticed that new Xcode 10 build system flags duplicated `Copy Bundle Resource` Info.plist files as errors, so I did make sure that there're no duplicated entries, but probably this error is not related to this fact.

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Okay, seems like I managed to solve it. I was having `/bin/sh` script in `Build Phases` that was trying to build fat static library. In the script, I had `OBJROOT` path set like this:

```
OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}"
```

Seems like Xcode 10 and new build system changed some paths on the way and this line was the source of the issue. It needs to be adjusted to:

```
OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds"
```

After that, `xcodebuild` manages to build this target without issues with new build system introduced in Xcode 10.

I didn't get to this solution by myself, big thanks to Matt Gallagher and his post in here: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlSignal/issues/24#issuecomment-396931001

---

As requested by @TMin in comment, here's how my script looks like:

```
set -e

# If we're already inside this script then die
if [ -n "$RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS" ]; then
exit 0
fi
export RW_MULTIPLATFORM_BUILD_IN_PROGRESS=1

RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME=${PROJECT_NAME}
RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB="lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"
RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION="${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/static/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}Sdk.framework"

function build_static_library {
    echo "1"
    echo "${BUILD_DIR}"
    # Will rebuild the static library as specified
    #     build_static_library sdk
    xcrun xcodebuild -project "${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}" \
    -target "${TARGET_NAME}" \
    -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" \
    -sdk "${1}" \
    ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO \
    BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" \
    OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
    BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" \
    SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" $ACTION
}

function make_fat_library {
    # Will smash 2 static libs together
    #     make_fat_library in1 in2 out
    xcrun lipo -create "${1}" "${2}" -output "${3}"
}

# 1 - Extract the platform (iphoneos/iphonesimulator) from the SDK name
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([A-Za-z]+) ]]; then
RW_SDK_PLATFORM=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find platform name from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# 2 - Extract the version from the SDK
if [[ "$SDK_NAME" =~ ([0-9]+.*$) ]]; then
RW_SDK_VERSION=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
echo "Could not find sdk version from SDK_NAME: $SDK_NAME"
exit 1
fi

# 3 - Determine the other platform
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphoneos" ]; then
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphonesimulator
else
RW_OTHER_PLATFORM=iphoneos
fi

# 4 - Find the build directory
if [[ "$BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR" =~ (.*)$RW_SDK_PLATFORM$ ]]; then
RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}"
else
echo "Could not find other platform build directory."
exit 1
fi

# Build the other platform.
build_static_library "${RW_OTHER_PLATFORM}${RW_SDK_VERSION}"

# If we're currently building for iphonesimulator, then need to rebuild
#   to ensure that we get both i386 and x86_64
if [ "$RW_SDK_PLATFORM" == "iphonesimulator" ]; then
build_static_library "${SDK_NAME}"
fi

# Join the 2 static libs into 1 and push into the .framework
make_fat_library "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${RW_INPUT_STATIC_LIB}" \
"${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}Sdk"

# Ensure that the framework is present in both platform's build directories
cp -a "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}Sdk" \
"${RW_OTHER_BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/static/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}Sdk.framework/Versions/A/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}Sdk"

# Copy the framework to the project directory
ditto "${RW_FRAMEWORK_LOCATION}" "${SRCROOT}/Frameworks/static/${RW_FRAMEWORK_NAME}Sdk.framework"
```

Problem is in `build_static_library` method in this line:

```
OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" \
```

Changing that line to:

```
OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependantBuilds" \
```

solves the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution.  I was getting caught up on this as well.

Comment: Can you add more details, please. Perhaps you could add a copy of your script so others can see how you are using this variable and why the wrong path was creating this issue. Thanks

Comment: @TMin Added it to my answer. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not solve the issue for me (I didn't use `${OBJROOT}` in my project)

Comment: @fabb Oh, too bad. In case you manage to solve your issue, please post your answer in here, it might be useful for people who might encounter issue like yours.

Comment: In my case I was having an error "error: accessing build database .../Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db: disk I/O error", I added the "OBJROOT" parameter and it solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: What is the value of `${OBJROOT}` here??

Comment: @Hisenberg It should be this: https://pewpewthespells.com/blog/buildsettings.html#objroot

Comment: I am facing the same exact issue in react native, can someone help me with that, would appreciate it,  Thanks

Comment: @MuhammadQasimQadri: React Native does generate Xcode native project under the hood for you. You can find it inside of "YOUR_APP_DIRECTORY/ios" directory. There, you can open .xcworkspace file with Xcode if it exists or if it doesn't exist, then .xcodeproj file. After Xcode is opened, you can pretty much do the same thing inside of the Xcode project settings.

Answer (score 53):

[Open XCode File->Project Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQ8qA.png)

[Build System->Legacy Build System](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rfima.png)

Configure XCode of version 10.0 project settings can solve the problem.

Comment: Can anyone explain to me the difference it is making?

Answer (score 22):

If you use build script to build submodule's libraries like me.
You also need to disable new build system in your build script explicitly by using `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO` in your xcodebuild command.

For example:

```
xcodebuild -configuration "${CONFIGURATION}" -project "${PROJECT_NAME}.xcodeproj" -target "${TARGET_NAME}" -sdk "${OTHER_SDK_TO_BUILD}" ${ACTION} RUN_CLANG_STATIC_ANALYZER=NO BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" SYMROOT="${SYMROOT}" -UseModernBuildSystem=NO
```

Comment: I am actually using this in some of my build scripts, just forgot to update my answer with these instructions as well. Thanks for mentioning this solution, it's nice one, I like it.

Comment: This had seemed to work to remove the 'database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location', however I'm faced with 'error: error: accessing build database "/Users/MyFolder/XCBuildData/build.db": disk I/O error', Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 12):

Deleting the Derived Data worked for me.
See how you can do it: https://programmingwithswift.com/delete-derived-data-xcode/

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the project is built, next time there is no and error. And the solution that helps me is to edit scheme and switch off Parallelize Build.

Comment: Pretty interesting. Nothing comes up to my mind which might be causing this in your case. Thanks for sharing the solution!

Comment: Xcode 13.3 same here

Answer (score 1):

For me, I just cleaned my project.
Restarted the IDE & rebuilt the project & it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Use this script it will it is working fine with new build system

```
# Step 1 search RECURSION and if detected stop "*/

if [ "true" == ${ALREADYINVOKED:-false} ]
then
echo "RECURSION: Detected, stopping"
else
export ALREADYINVOKED="true"

UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal

# Step 2. Build Device and Simulator versions

xcodebuild -target logger ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

xcodebuild -target logger-configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphonesimulator -arch i386 -arch x86_64 BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}"

# make sure the output directory exists
mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}"

# Step 3. Create universal binary file using lipo
lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/lib${PROJECT_NAME}universal.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/lib${PROJECT_NAME}.a"

# Last touch. copy the header files. Just for convenience
cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/include" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUTFOLDER}/"

fi
```

> before Xcode 10 build system uses single thread, but in Xcode 10 usees new build system with multiple threads, so every time you run your build Xcode run button  this script

```
 xcodebuild -target logger ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} -sdk iphoneos BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}".
```

will call one more time for build so on,  that will create RECURSION

Don't forgot to end you Script With (fi) its end of IF condition

Step 1 is to Detect RECURSION and stop them

Comment: What do you mean by `RECURSION`? And how do we stop it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the XCode 10 default build system but still running your build outside of the IDE (in a CI machine for instance), just replace your `-target` parameter for the `-scheme` parameter in your `xcodebuild` command like:

```
xcodebuild -scheme SchemeName -configuration Release clean build
```

Thanks to [this](https://www.mulle-kybernetik.com/weblog/2015/xcodebuild_driving_me_nuts_ag.html) post from 2015 that talks about a very similar problem and it gave me the hint to solve this problem. As the same author says,

> I would hazard a guess, that `xcodebuild` without a scheme goes
>   wrongly through the "modern build system", giving the mentioned error

Answer (score 0):

Adding a **Clean derived data** step in my build scripts (before an Xcode build) seems to fix the problem for me.

Not sure if it's related, but my project uses Realm (installed with CocoaPods). This is the GitHub issue that inspired the "fix" -> https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/5812.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue when running `swift run <your_proj>`.

A quick fix can be achieved by deleting the `build.db` file, along with its sibling files and directories. This may seem trifle, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issues when I upgraded by builds to **New Build System** because of xcframeworks requirements.

*Error: ".....Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location."*

The build was previously working fine when triggered with `xcodebuild( )`

None of the above/approved answered worked for me.

What worked for me was a switch from `xcodebuild( )` to `build_app( )` in my Fastlane script.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you have in your podfile an incompatible version to make sure open the runner.xcodeproj with xcode and see the version then go and see podfile to make sure it is the same and uncommented if not make them the same.

Answer (score 0):

Just Clean Build Folder will resolve this issue