# Xcode 10 beta 6 error: accessing build database

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

Hello I have a script to create a universal framework on Xcode 10. When I run it from Xcode everything works fine but if I tried from command line tool I receive the following error:

```
Build system information
error: error: accessing build database "/path/build.db": disk I/O error
```

Does anybody face a similar issue?

Comment: Did you try searching? I see a number of possibly helpful posts. For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error

Comment: Hey @matt yes I already tried those solutions and still have the problem

Comment: Ok, thanks, just checking!

Comment: I just ran into this with the production build. I built again, and now it works... ? "Build failed. Error accessing build database. (dir) Not an error." I didn't change anything that I'm aware of

Comment: Hey David, did you get a solution for this issue? I am facing similar issue, but none of the solutions on the other link appear relevant to me.

Comment: hey @HarishJ at the end I changed my xcodebuild command to this way: sudo xcodebuild -project YourProject.xcodeproj -target YourProject-Universal -destination "platform=iOS,name=generic/iOS" OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds" using this form it will work

Comment: Check my answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error/54021423#54021423](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error/54021423#54021423) if you want to keep the modern build system without overriding the OBJROOT variable or using the `sudo`

Comment: @Delfín thanks will check it out!!

Answer (score 12):

I finally found the solution for this one :)

When you build the **"Aggregated Target"**, i.e. the target that contains the script with the:

`lipo -create -output ...`

you need to run the `xcodebuild` command with `-UseModernBuildSystem=NO`

For example:

```
xcodebuild -target OBFramework -UseModernBuildSystem=NO
```

Comment: Does it use the legacy build system instead? Is it a workaround?

Comment: with xcode 12 legacy build system is deprecated so this workaround does not really work anymore. Any other suggestions @Oded Regev