# Xcode 10 Buildscript not running anymore

Tags: ios, xcode, xcodebuild, xcode10

I have a Buildscript integrated in my build settings. With Xcode 9 it was running smoothly. But since XCode 10 its not running anymore and gives me the following error:

```
error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database ".../build/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.
```

I already tried the solution which I found here:

[Xcode 10: unable to attach DB error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error)

But this didnt help me. Still having the issue...

UPDATE: If I switch to "Legacy Build Settings" I get this error:

```
Prepare build
```

note: Using legacy build system

```
Build Preparation
Couldn't update module cache session file'/var/folders/xh/zc0g0hp13j982ws3qhlr09nm0000gn/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/10.0-10A255/Xcode/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation': The item couldn’t be saved because the file name “Session.modulevalidation” is invalid.

** BUILD FAILED **

Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 65
```

Comment: Try reverting to the legacy build system.

Comment: Already did... Gives me another error. I updated my question...

Comment: Quit Xcode, delete DerivedData, delete Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode, restart computer, try again.

Comment: Just tried your suggestions. Same error after restart...

Comment: I'm out of ideas (esp. given you've provided no reproducible info). File a bug with Apple and revert to Xcode 9 is all I can suggest.

Comment: This is sadly not a solution as I have to use Swift 4.2...