# iOS Xcode 10 How to fix broken "New build system" - build.db: database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds

Tags: ios12, build-system, xcode10.1

I'm having problem with the infamous:

> "/Users/n/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Build/Intermediates/XCBuildData/build.db":
>   database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in
>   the same filesystem location

**How do I fix broken "modern" build system getting stuck with a locked database?**

I tried:

- Cleaning the project
- Deleting derived data
- Updating cocoapods (sudo gem...) and pod install
- Full nuking of Xcode folder with a fresh reinstall from App Store

Now I'm with a fresh Xcode installation, the project worked for a dozen builds(real device and simulator) and the problem comes back, making me unable to work on a project. **How I can reset the locks on build.db or delete it?**

I see this question asked multiple times, and the answers do not solve my problem. I'm not using build scripts, all I have is a couple cocoapods. Please do not close this question, as I'm asking specifically about lack of:

- NO CUSTOM SCRIPTS
- NO CONSOLE BUILDS
- NO COMPOSITE TARGETS

The only thing that lets me continue working is turning to the legacy build system:

[image]

[image]

[How can I use the legacy build system with Xcode 10's `xcodebuild`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51205221/how-can-i-use-the-legacy-build-system-with-xcode-10s-xcodebuild)

[Xcode 10: unable to attach DB error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error)

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this when tinkering with cli, `swift run democli`. The error I got was:

```
unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database "/Users/xman/Desktop/democli/.build/x86_64-apple-macosx/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.
```

I just remove the `build.db`, and the `DB error` is gone.

Answer (score 1):

So far the only way to fix this is to turn the "Legacy Build system" on in File > Workspace settings. After certain number of computer restarts (or time elapsed?) the setting can be changed to the "new" build system again and it will build.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to compile my project by adding to the `xcodebuild` command line:

```
OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}/DependentBuilds"
```

Thanks to this post: https://github.com/mattgallagher/CwlSignal/issues/24#issuecomment-396931001

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue while using **Fastlane** and the **New Build System**.

After switching from `xcodebuild( )` to `build_app( )`, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The legacy build solution is too temporary. You can only use that from within XCode. You can't use it within VSCode, so you lose the Hot Reload sweetness.