# How to access Azure storage account to upload files in iOS

Tags: ios, azure

How will I access Azure storage account in iOS. I have followed Microsoft official documentation but not able to generate the framework. pod(**'AZSClient'**) is also not working. I am using Xcode 13.2.1. I have followed this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-ios-how-to-use-blob-storage

Comment: You need to provide more details about the error you get when you tried to generate the framework, or when trying to install the pod.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database "/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AZSClient-aszpyyychypdacfvgvsqmqhwovsm/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db": database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in the same filesystem location.

This is the error which I am getting right now when trying to generate the framework. @AnandSowmithiran

Comment: Steps which I have followed:
First, download or clone the azure-storage-ios repo.
Go into azure-storage-ios -> Lib -> Azure Storage Client Library, and open AZSClient.xcodeproj in Xcode.
At the top-left of Xcode, change the active scheme from "Azure Storage Client Library" to "Framework".
Build the project (⌘+B). This will create an AZSClient.framework file on your Desktop.

Comment: I am not so sure but try one of the answers for this SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error)

Comment: I have checked the link but I don't have OBJROOT="${OBJROOT}" in the script under build phase @AnandSowmithiran