# Xcode build fail: Requested but did not find extension point

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I followed the official react-native setup guide to set up my react-native project. (installing all required packages + `npx react-native init MyProject` + `npx react-native start` (Terminal 1) + `npx react-native run-ios` (Terminal 2)) However, I get an error when trying to build the ios application. [This Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51153525/xcode-10-unable-to-attach-db-error) did not seem to help.

I would highly appreciate if you could help me out. This is my first react-native setup so I have no idea how to fix that error.

Here is the full output when running `npx react-native run-ios`:

> (base) Lucas-MacBook-Pro-2:MyProject luca$ npx react-native run-ios
> info Found Xcode workspace "MyProject.xcworkspace" info Launching
> iPhone 13 (iOS 15.2) info Building (using "xcodebuild -workspace
> MyProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyProject
> -destination id=D3DC5A60-6CB5-40B5-B610-4760B38C1941") error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with
> error code 65. To debug build logs further, consider building your app
> with Xcode.app, by opening MyProject.xcworkspace. Command line
> invocation:
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace MyProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme MyProject -destination id=D3DC5A60-6CB5-40B5-B610-4760B38C1941
>
> User defaults from command line:
> IDEPackageSupportUseBuiltinSCM = YES
>
> note: Using new build system note: Planning Analyze workspace
>
> Create build description Build description signature:
> 58652ba6d5e25b644cfcef8d1c74529a Build description path:
> /Users/luca/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-eqgmgatmlgqlskcmpchtodpmmbab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/58652ba6d5e25b644cfcef8d1c74529a-desc.xcbuild
>
> note: Build preparation complete note: Building targets in dependency
> order error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database
> "/Users/luca/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyProject-eqgmgatmlgqlskcmpchtodpmmbab/Build/Intermediates.noindex/XCBuildData/build.db":
> database is locked Possibly there are two concurrent builds running in
> the same filesystem location.
>
> 2022-05-08 12:19:42.347 xcodebuild[2512:185622] Requested but did not
> find extension point with identifier
> Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in
> com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore 2022-05-08 12:19:42.353
> xcodebuild[2512:185622] Requested but did not find extension point
> with identifier
> Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension
> Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of
> plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
> ** BUILD FAILED **

To check all version information, here is the output of `npx react-native info`:

> System:
> OS: macOS 12.0.1
> CPU: (8) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8279U CPU @ 2.40GHz
> Memory: 31.59 MB / 8.00 GB
> Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
> Binaries:
> Node: 14.16.1 - /usr/local/bin/node
> Yarn: Not Found
> npm: 6.14.12 - /usr/local/bin/npm
> Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
> Managers:
> CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
> SDKs:
> iOS SDK:
> Platforms: DriverKit 21.4, iOS 15.4, macOS 12.3, tvOS 15.4, watchOS 8.5
> Android SDK: Not Found
> IDEs:
> Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
> Xcode: 13.3.1/13E500a - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
> Languages:
> Java: 16.0.1 - /usr/bin/javac
> npmPackages:
> @react-native-community/cli: Not Found
> react: 17.0.2 => 17.0.2
> react-native: 0.68.1 => 0.68.1
> react-native-macos: Not Found
> npmGlobalPackages:
> *react-native*: Not Found

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Quick fix:**

1. Manually download Xcode Command Line Tools from https://developer.apple.com
2. Activate downloaded command line tools using `sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
3. Restart Xcode
4. (only for official react-native setup): Comment out these lines from ios/Podfile:
   `use_flipper!()`
   `# post_install do |installer|`
   `react_native_post_install(installer)`
   `__apply_Xcode_12_5_M1_post_install_workaround(installer)`
   `end`
5. (only for official react-native setup): Run `pod update`

**Description of what went wrong:**
I was finally able to fix the problem. Since I simply followed the setup guide for MacOs as described [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup), I think it is useful to elaborate on what I did in to fix the issue described above. Some people may face the same difficulties.

First things first: The underlying error is caused by Xcode itself.

> error: unable to attach DB: error: accessing build database [...]

is only the consequence of the other two errors from the output, namely

> Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode [...]

These errors occur when running the application for the first time. When trying to restart the application, the earlier instance of the program still tries to access the database which causes the error.

Therefore, I will explain how to fix the missing dependencies `Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS` and `Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS`. I found out how to fix that error based on [this Apple Community post](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/703233). In my case, I had to manually install Xcode Command Line Tools from the [Apple Developer Website](https://developer.apple.com). Next, Xcode has to integrate these downloaded command line tools using `sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`. Once you have restarted Xcode and followed the official setup guide from react-native you will face another build error.

This error will occur because the initial Xcode configuration collides with the Podfile generated by `npm react-native init MyProject` on ios. To fix this, comment out lines from the podfile (see 4.) and after running `pod update`, your setup of react-native should finally work.

I hope that I was able to help a couple of lost developers who want to get started with React Native for ios Apps.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I just select Command Line Tools inside Xcode preferences
[image: preferences]

Comment: Confirming that select box was empty until I chose Xcode 13.4.1 and error has disappeared now from zsh terminal.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed running only:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
```

Already had the command line tools installed, and I'm not using any react, I guess the issue was caused by switching xcode versions recently.

Comment: This command messed up everything